# Cannot active my account

Tags: php, email

I'm trying secure more my member system.
So basicly if somebody wants to create an account he needs to activate it by email.

Now when I receive an email with the activation code: he says `We cannot find that email` This is strange since the email is in the database.

I got a script called `activate.php`

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['succes']) === true && empty ($_GET['succes']) === true) {
?>
    <h2>Thanks, your account has been activated!</h2>
<?php
} else if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['email_code']) === true) {
    $email  = trim($_GET['email']);
    $email_code = trim($_GET['email_code']);
    $user = new User();
    if($user->email_exists($email) === false) {
        echo 'We cannot find that email';
    } else if ($user->activate($email, $email_code) === false) {
        echo 'problem activate your account';
    }
}

?>
```

In the classes dir I got a file called `User.php`
The activate function

```
function activate ($email, $email_code) {
    $email  = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $email_code = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);
    require_once '../config.php';
    if ($db->get($db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
        $db->query("UPDATE `users` SET `group` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the email_exists function:

```
function email_exists($email) {
return ($this->_db->get($this->_db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: You're not escaping `$email` in `email_exists`. As a general rule, never assign the output of `mysql_real_escape_string` to a variable but always just make it part of the query. Else it may get very confusing what you did and did not secure.

Comment: May i suggest you always 'base64_enode()' stuff that you send out via HTML that you want to survive being unchanged in the url.  If you want to ensure it has a time life then include a timestamp. If you want to ensure that it isn't changed then include a hash. Maybe a long string but will not be messed with. This applies to your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and urldecode funcitons while inserting/gettind email from url

```
$email  = urldecode(trim($_GET['email']));
...
$url = 'http://site/?email='urlencode($email);
```

Check this:

```
function email_exists($email) {
    var_dump($email);exit;
    return ($this->_db->get($this->_db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: still receiving the problem

Comment: $email is working, But it seems he isn't selecting from mysql